# Is there a way to download all Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, bulk-download

I know that you can download a ZIP file of all Google Docs, but I have so many documents that the download fails and Google sends me an email with a list of errors about exceeding file size.

What is the best way to download a *lot* of Google Docs efficiently - and preferably as PDFs?

Answer (score 3):

Google Takeout Can help you to liberate your data from Google. Check this link.

https://www.google.com/settings/takeout

Comment: Hi, thanks @Waqar .Very interesting! Nevertheless, I don't see any google docs in this list. Which option should we chose for this?

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION THAT WORKED FOR ME IN 2020**

- Open Google Drive
- In search bar, type "type:document"
- Scroll down the pages till you find/list the last element in the list
- Click an element and select all (Ctrl + A)
- Right click > Download
- It will prompt for "Leave the page"
- Click "Leave"
- A zip file will be downloaded now.

Comment: Thanks Naveen, but i think the questions is for google docs and not google drive

Comment: @PedroReis All the google docs will be saved in the Google drive quota. Hence searching google file formats (documents, sheets, ...) in google drive is applicable.